# Thread exit callback

Tags: java, thread-safety

I need to be able to inject some exit code for the current running thread. I have struggled with this one for a while, and i finally came up with a solution here is some code similar to what I am doing:

```
public static void injectThreadExitCallback(final Runnable callback) {
    final curr = Thread.currentThread();
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                curr.join();
                callback.run();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ... logging ...
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

It seems to work fine and does exactly what I'm wanting, my only concern is, if this causes any leaking or other undesired side effects, that i may not bee seeing.

or is this perfectly fine, if so this is pretty useful. I could see a simple library that can dynamically add exit code to existing threads.

Comment: Looks fine; just be aware that the callback will be running on a separate thread.

Comment: Moving the callback to the `finally` block means it will run if `join` throws an exception which will happen *before* the target thread has exited. Also,  join won't ever throw an exception unless some outside agent starts interrupting all the threads.

Comment: If the anonymous thread that you create inside this method is interrupted, it's highly questionable whether the callback should be invoked. The point of interrupting a thread is to stop what it is doing. Since the only thing this thread is doing is waiting to invoke the callback, the only reason to interrupt it would be to prevent the callback from running.

Comment: Sorry im a noob when i comes to understanding threading behaviors. @Ted you are absolutely correct there is no point to moving to callback outside of the try catch, the only exceptions that are caught are the "InterruptedException" and it might be more desired behavior the way i had it before.

Thank you all for your feed back!

Answer (score 6):

You better do

```
new Thread () {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        try
        {
            // Thread logic here
        }
        finally
        {
            // Thread exit logic here
        }
    }
}.start ();
```

Comment: good point! that way if the thread I'm wrapping dies ill still get to do what i need to do.

Comment: That's not exactly injection, is it? The thread code needs to be modified to incorporate the thread exit logic. (Or are you talking about restructuring OP's suggested behavior injection thread?

Comment: I think he was saying i need to move my callback in case of exceptions, i think.

Comment: "Thread exit logic" may include calling some callback or fireXXX method, of cause.

Comment: @NickHecht - What exceptions? Nobody has a reference to the injector thread, so there's no way to interrupt it. (And arguably, if it was interrupted, you wouldn't want to invoke the callback anyway.) No other exceptions can be raised by `curr.join()`.

Comment: @Tedd if the thread I'm wrapping "Thread.currentThread()" throws an InterruptedException. before I had put my callback inside of the try block, so the callback wouldn't of been called. Also say i have some resources that I'm providing if the thread dies i still want to be able to close those resources. But these are implementation details, i think it depends on how im using it whether or not i need to callback in the case of a exception.

Comment: @NickHecht - If thread `curr` dies for any reason (including an uncaught exception), `curr.join()` will _not_ throw an exception; it will simply return and execution will proceed normally. The only exception that `curr.join()` can throw is an `InterruptedException`, and that only if the (anonymous) thread created inside `injectThreadExitCallback` is interrupted.

Answer (score 3):

You can't possibly inject code into a running thread unless that thread is actively cooperating, like for example the Event Dispatch Thread in AWT, which at its root has a loop that takes Runnables off of a queue and executes them.

Your design may introduce data races into code that was previously single-threaded and thus had no concurrency issues.

Finally, the design wastes a precious system resource (a thread) to do nothing but wait for another thread to finish.

If you need this to patch up some existing code from the outside, then it may be the only option; if not, it would be better to provide an explicit mechanism for it that was more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `callback.run();` after the `catch` block or in `final` block if you want to ensure that it is called anyways

Comment: Generally speaking, the only reason to interrupt a thread is to get it to stop doing what it is doing. In this case, the only thing it is doing is waiting to invoke the callback. Thus, you definite do _not_ want to ensure that the callback is invoked when the thread is interrupted!

Comment: This true, but it depend on the application logic weather your want to ensure that the `callback` is called or no. So for example, if the `callback` is doing some cleaning task, you will have a legitimate reason to ensure that it is called even if the thread is interrupted.